# How does one provide input to this page?

Tags: discussion

[Updating Marlin Firmware - Step by Step Guide](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/12153/updating-marlin-firmware-step-by-step-guide)

Page asks for step by step updates, but is locked for comments, answers, or edits.  How does one help?

Comment: You should ask this on meta. I've flagged for it to be moved, so you don't have to do anything except maybe flag for a moderator to move it over for you.

Comment: I have spent the last day weriting out the most needed configuration.h changes into the answer. At the moment the steps 2 and 3 are rather short and nondescript - and you can chime in by now.

Answer (score 2):

Users with a high enough reputation were able to edit the question and the answer, it has been locked for lower reputation users to prevent adding other answers while we were establishing a framework for the answer. Once the answer is visible the whole community will be able to add to the answer within the framework of the answer. Note that we possibly will lock the addition of new answers.

Comment: the version 1 is up - revision time!

Answer (score 0):

The question was locked when several of the vets [0scar and me mainly] were working on the infancy of the answer - it was 2 days of a hot mess as we went through the source code to find all the essential settings we usually forget after we have set them for our own machine distributions - if we even do our own distribution and not take one from another that was so kind to make it for the same machine.